# SAMBA shared folder creation for the users on Integrated Active Directory setup

Tags: centos, active-directory, samba

I have a centos SAMBA server integrated with AD. All the users from AD will have a home folder in the SAMBA Server. The home folder is created whenever the user try to access the SAMBA Server. Now I would like to change the setup style. I want to create a SAMBA folder whenever a user is created or added to a particular group in the Active Directory. How can I achieve this? Please help.